# Layout changed after I created a team. How can I get the old layout back?

Tags: support, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

I created a team yesterday. Since then, the layout of the page where it shows all the questions on the searched thing has changed. Now it shows both answers and questions and does not show the filters option which is not what I want. How can I revert to the old layout? Here are examples of the layouts in images-

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image: After]

Comment: You don't.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine What do you mean?

Comment: Request to delete the team and wait for 30 days.

Comment: @ayhan But that's way too long. Isn't there a faster solution?

Comment: Create a throwaway account, make it part of the team, make that account team admin/owner, leave the team with your main account.

Comment: @yivi Thankssss it works!!!!

Comment: While this is an important consideration to raise for the SO design team, the screenshots you shared above don't reflect the same view: the 'before' is a logged out view. If you log out after joining a team you should still see the same view as the 'before' picture. Your 'before' should depict what SO looks like while logged in (and not a member of a team).

Comment: @TylerH I used a logged out pic bcs I didn’t have an alternate account to test it from so I tested it through incognito mode

Comment: @TylerH Anyway I replaced the picture in question.

Comment: Teams has now been split out into separate domain, thus resolving this issue.